# app js in the login page accessible to unauthorized user

Tags: spring, security, extjs

I am using spring with ext js for my web application. Un- authorized users able to access app.js file. Please suggest how to protect it.

Comment: Since its client side so you dont have any restrictions on these things. Hacks may happen undoubtedly . One thing you can do is load minimal code upfront i.e. lazy loading along. Due to this it will impact less on your site.

Comment: I want to redirect unauthorized user to login page or show that it is not accessible whenever someone tries to access app.js directly.

Comment: See, you can restrict right click on page to refrain user from opening dev-console. But anyways he can open it through keyboard shortcut. What I am saying is to expose minimal code to user when present on login page. Even bank website cannot avoid opening of the console.